# Disabling ArcMap warning prompt?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Whenever I'm attempting to perform `Switch selection` in ArcMap table I'm always presented with this friendly prompt:

[image]

I'm fully aware of 'dangers' of this operation, and I think I could live without this warning.

Is there a way to switch it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HowTo:  Turn off "This table (potentially) contains a large number of records..." warning message](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17414)

> Summary
>
> The table window in ArcMap provides a 'Select All' command and a
>   'Switch Selection' command. When there is a large number of records in
>   a table, 'Switch Selection' and 'Select All' could potentially take a
>   long time to complete. A warning message allows you to cancel the
>   operation. If you always want to perform the operation, you may want
>   to turn off this warning message.
>
> Procedure
>
> Click Selection > Options. Uncheck the Warning Threshold check box.
>
> Alternatively, you can adjust the record count at which the message is
>   displayed.

Although its an old paper, I can confirm it works in 10:

[image]